# 0-5 to 0-12 volt level shifter at high frequency

Tags: mosfet, pwm, power-electronics

what is the best way to shift PWM at 500kHZ from logic level 0-5 volt to 0-12 volt to drive a mosfet?

answers here were no good they only work for lower frequency and pwm is distorted at 500kHZ

[Level shift circuit MCU to MOSFET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/152132/level-shift-circuit-mcu-to-mosfet?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[High Frequency Logic Level Conversion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/135767/high-frequency-logic-level-conversion/207274#207274)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is to buy a gate driver IC, that's what they are designed to do- level shift and drive a large capacitive load quickly.

For example, the [NCP81074](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCP81074-D.PDF) can drive a 12V 1.8nF load with rise and fall times of 4ns typical. There are hundreds of different types, from many manufacturers.

Comment: unfortunately, i couldn't find those gate drivers in local stores and exporting it where i live cost high taxes and long shipping period(too much for a little project), i only could find tlp250 which work on 25kHz max

Comment: 500kHz is a pretty high-tech operating frequency. Maybe consider using a lower switching frequency (which means bigger magnetics). You can also do it by using relatively small MOSFETs with a low value resistor for the level shifter (wastes power).